# Is my solution to this power factor question correct?

Tags: power, ac, power-factor-correction

I'd be very thankful if it would be possible for someone to check my solution to this question and highlight any mistakes which I may have made in the working. I have checked through it myself several times and am pretty confident that it is correct - I would just appreciate a second opinion.

[image: Power Factor Question]

[image: Solution part a]

[image: Solution part b]

Comment: Wow, you did an impressive job of creating the graphic image of your work! Why would you do that if you were still trying to make sure the answer is correct? Is it possible that you got this answer somewhere on the internet and you want us to check it for you before you hand it in? And no, it is not entirely correct.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson The question came from the internet, there was no solution with it. I did the solution and created the images myself. The solution is 100% my own work. I created the images using Circuit Wizard which is essentially a PCB design package. Don't let your cynicism cloud your judgement! I'd appreciate it if you could let me know if and where you found error(s) in it so that I can correct it. The reason for creating it is to add it to my design file for future use if and when required plus the interest and enjoyment of doing it and learning from it.

Comment: Why don't you just run a simulation to check it? Where did you get the question such that there was no solution provided as well?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson A simulation is not an unreasonable suggestion. The question came from this site some time ago but was deleted a little while after it appeared before anybody got the chance to answer it - not that it would have been answered as it appeared to be homework without any attempt at a solution. I found it to be an interesting question and I just managed to grab it before it disappeared.